# How to set proxy while using urllib3.PoolManager in python

Tags: python, proxy, connection-pooling, urllib3

I am currently using connection pool provided by urllib3 in python like the following,

```
pool = urllib3.PoolManager(maxsize = 10)
resp = pool.request('GET', 'http://example.com')
content = resp.read()
resp.release_conn()
```

However, I don't know how to set proxy while using this connection pool. I tried to set proxy in the 'request' like `pool.request('GET', 'http://example.com', proxies={'http': '123.123.123.123:8888'}` but it didn't work.

Can someone tell me how to set the proxy while using connection pool

Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example for how to use a proxy with urllib3 in the [Advanced Usage section of the documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#proxies). I adapted it to fit your example:

```
import urllib3
proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager('http://123.123.123.123:8888/', maxsize=10)
resp = proxy.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
content = resp.read()
# You don't actually need to release_conn() if you're reading the full response.
# This will be a harmless no-op:
resp.release_conn()
```

The `ProxyManager` behaves the same way as a `PoolManager` would.

Comment: it seems that you only use ProxyManager without PoolManager, or the connection pool will still be established while using ProxyManager?

Comment: The ProxyManager is a substitute for a PoolManager. Underneath, everything still uses ConnectionPools, so don't worry. :)

Comment: I see, but in this case, can I specify the "maxsize" of the connection pool and the number of pools.

Comment: ProxyManager works the same way, you can give it `maxsize` too. I updated the example.